# k8s - Nested Firecracker Environments

Tags: kubernetes, firecracker, kata-containers

Sorry if this question might sound "convoluted" but here it goes...

I'm currently designing a k8s solution based on Firecracker and Kata-containers. I'd like the environment to be as isolated/secure as possible. My thoughts around this are:

1. deploy k8s masters as Firecracker nodes having API-server,
   Controller, Scheduler and etcd
2. deploy k8s workers as Firecracker nodes having Kubelet, Kube-proxy and using Kata-containers + Firecracker for
   deployed workload. The workload will be a combination of MQTT cluster components and in-house developed FaaS components (probably using OpenFaaS)

It's point 2 above which makes me feel a little awkward/convoluted. Am I over complicating things, introducing complexity which will cause problems related to (CNI) networking among worker nodes etc? Isolation and minimizing attack vectors are all important, but maybe I'm trying "to be too much of a s.m.a.r.t.a.s.s" here :)

I really like the concept with Firecrackers microVM architecture with reduced security risks and reduced footprint and it would make for a wonderful solution to tenant isolation. However, am I better of to use another CRI-conforming runtime together with Kata for the actual workload being deployed on the workers?

Many thanks in advance for your thoughts/comments on this!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/weaveworks-liquidmetal and consider whether contributing to that would get you further towards your goal? alternative runtimes (like kata) for different workloads are welcomed in PR’s. There is a liquid-metal slack channel in the Weaveworks user group of you have any queries. Disclosure I currently work at Weaveworks :)

Comment: Hi! This is sounds *very* interesting. I'll definitely go there and have a look. I currently use Ignite so I'm already a "Weave junkie"... :) Thanks for the link!